# Ошибка в формуле точек полигона

Tags: c#, winforms, math

Приветствую!

Решил написать простую программку, которая бы рисовала многоугольник в зависимости от начальной точки, радиуса и количества углов, собственно сам метод, который формирует `Point` :

```
private void PolygonPoints()
{
    double angle = -Math.PI * 0.5;
    Points = new Point[Corners];
    for (int i=0; i< Corners; i++)
    {
        Points[i] = new Point 
        ( Xstrt + (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(angle + Math.PI * 2.0 * i/ Corners) * Radius),
          Ystrt + (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(angle + Math.PI * 2.0 * i/ Corners) * Radius));
    }
}
```

Однако получается, что все точки лежат на одной прямой. Подскажите, где ошибся ?

Comment: У вас для X и Y используется косинус.

Comment: @Bulson да, спасибо не заметил. поставил sin для X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, у тебя же даже в коде видно, что формулы для вычисления `X` и `Y` абсолютно идентичны и имеют линейную зависимость от `i`

```
Xstrt + (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(angle + Math.PI * 2.0 * i/ Corners) * Radius)

Ystrt + (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(angle + Math.PI * 2.0 * i/ Corners) * Radius)
```

Вот ты и получаешь прямую линию. Может, ты хотел использовать синус для одной из координат? А для того чтобы перевести целочисленный индекс в табличный, нужно хотя бы знать ширину этой таблицы.

```
int index = y * width + x;
```

Тогда:

```
int y = index / width;

int x = index % width;
```

В твоём случае Corners - это не ширина, а суммарное количество точек, поэтому ты опять же получишь прямую линию.